# Registration isn't working

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I wrote jsp to handle registration. Here is the code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*, java.io.*, java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*, javax.servlet.http.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%

    String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
    System.out.println(fname);
    String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
    System.out.println(lname);
    String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
    System.out.println(uname);
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/logindb", "root",
            "***");
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into members(first_name, last_name, email, uname, pass, regdate) values (?,?,?,?,?, CURDATE())");
    try {
        preparedStatement.setString(1, fname);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, lname);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, uname);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, email);
        preparedStatement.setString(5, password);
        preparedStatement.execute();
        connection.close();
        out.println("registration successful, click here to " + "<a href='login.do'>login</a>");
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
    }
    /* if(preparedStatement != null) {
        out.println("Registration successful, go to" + "<a href='login.do'> login</a>");
    } else {
        out.println("Registration is unsuccessful!");
    } */
    /* if (i>0) {
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.do");
    } */
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="fname">First name</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="lname">Last name</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="uname">User name</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="uname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="email">Email id</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <center>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="reg" value="Register"></td>
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <center>
                    <td><a href="login.do">Back to login</a></td>
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

When I executed it, the form values aren't going to java. Error is:

```
null
null
null
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'first_name' cannot be null
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1347)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:958)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1494)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.reg_jsp._jspService(reg_jsp.java:155)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Those `null` values are from html form. How can I fix it?

Comment: You are trying to insert null in first_name column of your db table, it is because it is declared as not null in table definition, check your column constraints

Comment: You can add value="some default value" in your input tags and then validate properly.This will guarantee there is never a null value

Comment: where is your form???

Comment: @Pirate: in same jsp file, check properly

Comment: Add your table tag to inside of `<form>`. `<form><table></table></form>`

Comment: I think my comment helps you. If helps I will add as answer ))

Comment: you must have to add your <table> inside <form> tag. Otherwise data will not be go to next page.

Comment: Please, add some condition before you build the PreparedStatement to be sure that the value are not null (for those how need it). Don't do it ONLY in javascript as the answer tell you. If I use your site with Javascript disable, I will end up with the worst scenario !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use validation on userside. Thats mean when a user dint enter the name or last name it should show some message that username can't be blank.

For that you can use java script for validation.

```js
function validation(){
var a=document.getElementById("name");
  if (a.value==""){
    alert("Name can't be empty");
    return false
    }
   else
     return true;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <form name="vali" onsubmit="return validation()" action="https://www.google.com">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Update your html file like this.**

```
<body>
 <form name="" action="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="fname">First name</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="lname">Last name</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="uname">User name</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="uname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="email">Email id</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <center>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="reg" value="Register"></td>
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <center>
                    <td><a href="login.do">Back to login</a></td>
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Even I enter values, I'm getting `null` values

Comment: you must have to add your <table> inside <form> tag. Otherwise data will not be go to next page.

Comment: Hope you get my point.

Comment: Perfecto... forgot to wrap `form` tag around `table` tag

Comment: Validation on client side ? Really the worst practice ! You can do a validation to be user friendly, but remember that the user is NEVER a friend, so validate your values on server side !! (It's easy to remove your validation or to override it)

Comment: yeah, both should be done,